# CPU usage is extremely high with below code

Tags: php, mysql, updates, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

I have used below code.
I'm new to PHP and Mysql...

Am I doing something wrong in loop.?

abc table has 70562 records ip2 table has 3833421 records..

Any suggestion for improvement.?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM abc where ip_country IS NULL";

$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row["subid"];
    $ip = $row["ip"];

    //Convert Ip to Number 
    $ipnumberconversion = ip2long($ip);

    //Select Ip From Ip Table
    $sql2 = "UPDATE abc as a ,
                    ip2 as b
            SET a.ip_state = b.REGION,
                a.ip_postalcode = b.ZIPCODE,
                a.ip_city = b.CITY, 
                a.ip_country = b.COUNTRY_NAME  
            WHERE a.subid = '$id' AND b.IP_FROM <= $ipnumberconversion AND b.IP_TO >= $ipnumberconversion";
    $query2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die (mysqli_error($con));
 }
```

Comment: `ip2long()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php exists, and even for mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton - you could use a SQL join instead of a loop to connect the two tables. Or in other words: Yes, your code is very inefficient.

Comment: looks like a one off thing? if so does it matter

Comment: exactly what's wrong with this code? high cpu usage isn't a programming "problem"... it's a design issue.

Comment: hardware is cheaper than labour, well that's what i tell my boss ;-)

Comment: Updated based on @Sven suggestions

Answer (score -2):

If you trying this on localhost, its normal. The biggest part of CPU usage cause the mysql process(concretely updating the values in table).

There are many possibilities. Low CPU performance, bad settings of MySQL,etc